# Java - change default floating point constant type from double to float

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I'm not sure if this is actually possible, but can I change default type for floating point numbers to float. It's double and most of android classes use float and I always have to cast.

Edit:
Well yes, I don't have to cast (float f = 1.0f) , but the `f` after each float is annoying. Isn't there some compiler option or something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you would need to do that other than Java's irksome lack of an implicit double-to-float conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare number as a float literal by appending low case `f` after the value, e.g.

```
float f = 1.0f;
```

With that no casts are required